# CSS to make partly visible div / element expand fully on mouseover

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create two divs side by side but because they are quite big I want only part of them to show up initially, then expand fully on mousover/click.

I see  [Hipmunk](http://hipmunk.com) doing a wonderful job of it for their Flight Search and Hotel Search.

Any ideas how this can be achieved?

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Can you update your profile and say something about your background such as: experience with HTML. CSS, JavaScript, otherwise it is hard to know how to pitch an answer.  Also say which country you are in... Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried? Have you checked how hipmunk does it? Show us some code, and ask a specific question when you get stuck...

Answer (score 0):

Apply a specific width and `overflow:hidden`.

On click/hover set a new width to show all the content.

Answer (score 0):

You would have found lots of related question on stackoverflow for this:

see these similar questions and solution:

[Expand / shrink div on hover / out with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12056950/expand-shrink-div-on-hover-out-with-jquery)

[Expand Div over others on mouse over jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15435827/expand-div-over-others-on-mouse-over-jquery)