# How to expand a div that upon expanding has four divs inside?

Tags: jquery, html

There's an animation I'm trying to create, I don't know what this animation is called so I'm not sure how to ask or search for what I want to do. I apologize if this has been asked here before.

Basically I want a `div` (square) to expand into a bigger `div` (square) which itself is contains 4 smaller `div`s (squares) when hovering, and when `mouseleave` it returns to the original `div`.

I'm not sure if this is clear.

I've tried `hide()`, `addClass()`, `removeClass()`, so many of them. `addClass` only helps me expand the div into a bigger div but I can't figure out how to include 4 smaller divs inside this expanded div.

Here's what I have so far:

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/95CCL/)

This is the part of the code where I try to include the four `div`s within expanded `div`:

```
<div class = 'expand'>
        <div id = 'a'></div>
        <div id = 'b'></div>
        <div id = 'c'></div>
        <div id = 'd'></div>
</div>
```

Comment: please create a http://jsfiddle.net/. nothing makes it clear than an example

Comment: add your code.
or provide a fiddle

Comment: try .append() to add the divs at mouseon. .remove() to remove them on mouseout.

Comment: It's too broad until you show us your effort what you've tried. Post your code in the question.

Comment: Maybe this thread can help you
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15435827/expand-div-over-others-on-mouse-over-jquery
Please search a bit more.

Comment: does your inner `div`s have any specific layout/arrangement? like are they just stacked on top of each other or do they for 2 rows and 2 columns? please specify.

Comment: @ArnelleBalane I'm trying to place my inner divs with ID a,b,c,d inside of the expanded div when the mouse hovers, thus dividing the expanded div into four sections.